# Finding the process with the maximum value mpi

Tags: c, ubuntu, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to find the maximum value among the threads using mpi point to point communication (also want to add the minimum value but not until I figured this out)
I've assumed that the processes formed a ring starting from 0 send to his right which is process 1
and I only want the process which has the maximum value to print the result, but unfortunately in some cases 2 process print out the result
anyone can tell where the problem is ??...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size, tag = 100;
    int rightrank, leftrank;
    int v, min, max, i, tmpmax, tmpmin;
    int *data;
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Status status;
    data = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    
    rightrank = rank + 1;
    leftrank = rank - 1;
    
    if (rank == 0) {
        leftrank = size - 1;
    }
    if (rank == size - 1) {
        rightrank = 0;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = rand() % 60;
    }
    v = data[rank];
    
//v=rank*10;
    printf("{rank %d , v = %d }\n", rank, v);
    
    if (rank == 0) {
        
        MPI_Send(&v, 1, MPI_INT, rightrank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        
        MPI_Recv(&tmpmax, 1, MPI_INT, leftrank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    else {
        
        MPI_Recv(&tmpmax, 1, MPI_INT, leftrank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        max = tmpmax;
        
        if (v > max) {
            max = v;
        }
        
        MPI_Send(&max, 1, MPI_INT, rightrank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        
    }
    
    if (v == max) {
        printf("Me process of rank %d i have max value v = %d\n ", rank, v);
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

output :
[as u can see rank 1 and 2 print ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mu8v.png)

Comment: There is no question in your post. Edit it to ask a specific question. If your code is not behaving as you want, you should prepare a [mre].

Comment: Use `MPI_Reduce`.

Comment: Side note: With the exception of a cast that's not necessary in C code, this is C, not C++, code. Using the C++ tag opens you up to a horde of "Why are you not using `std::vector`?" comments that may be of no value to you.

Comment: @Sneftel the question is to use point to point communication so without MPI_Reduce anyway I've tried MPI_Reduce and it worked but the question is only using send and recive

Comment: @VictorEijkhout can you please explain ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the max value ends up only in `tmpmax` on rank `0`. `if (v == max) ...` does not make sense to me.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I know there's something wrong with the code that's why I've asked here . how can I let the process who has the maximum value to print out ?? anyway I've attached a picture of the execution in the link

Comment: The answer is in my previous comment :-)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet do you mean I should let process 0 print out the maximum value ? but what about the rank of the process who has the max value ?

Comment: You are basically re-implenting MPI_Reduce(..., MPI_MAX ...) and that does not provide this info.

Comment: You could for example re-implement MPI_Allreduce(..., MPI_MAX, .. ) and have the rank(s) with the max value print their rank. Or re-implement MPI_Reduce(..., MPI_MAXLOC, ...) and have rank 0 print a rank that owns the max value.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the question is to display the rank of the process who has the max value as well the maximum value in 2 different ways : 1-first using point to point communication like here with only use of send,recv . 2- second using collective comm so without send,recv .the second version of the problem works fine for me but first one if not :( and still cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway thank you so much I've figure it out....
my solution is that let the process 0 make a loop and check which index has the maximum value like this :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
int rank,size,tag=100;
int rightrank,leftrank;
int v, min, max,i,tmpmax,tmpmin;
int* data;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
MPI_Status status;
data=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

rightrank=rank+1;
leftrank=rank-1;

if(rank==0){
leftrank=size-1;
}
if(rank==size-1){
rightrank=0;
}

for(i=0 ; i < size ; i ++){
    data[i]=rand()%80;
}
v=data[rank];

//v=rank*10;
printf("{rank %d , v = %d }\n",rank,v);

if(rank==0){

    MPI_Send(&v,1,MPI_INT,rightrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&v,1,MPI_INT,rightrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    MPI_Recv(&tmpmax,1,MPI_INT,leftrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&tmpmin,1,MPI_INT,leftrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

}
else{
MPI_Recv(&tmpmax,1,MPI_INT,leftrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
max=tmpmax;
if(v>max){
max=v;
}
MPI_Send(&max,1,MPI_INT,rightrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
sleep(0.1);
/////cal of min
MPI_Recv(&tmpmin,1,MPI_INT,leftrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
min=tmpmin;
if(v<min){
min=v;
}
MPI_Send(&min,1,MPI_INT,rightrank,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

if(rank==0){
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++){
    if(tmpmax==data[i]){
    printf("Me Process of rank %d i have the max value ,v = %d\n",i,tmpmax);
    }
}
}

if(rank==0){
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++){
    if(tmpmin==data[i]){
    printf("Me Process of rank %d i have the min value ,v = %d\n",i,tmpmin);
    }
}
}

MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works if the data array is the same on all nodes. Since it is populated with (pseudo) random numbers, that suggests a different issue

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet is there a better way to display the rank and the maximum value ?? and also here every process has its own private copy of the data array right ?? I mean if I print all the elements of the array by process 1 or 2 they can display the elements correctly right ?

Comment: I have a hard time following what you did. please post the full code and i will have a look.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've posted the full code in the answer, thank you

Comment: The rank you display is wrong since each MPI task has its own `data` array. I also do not understand why `data` is an array instead of a scalar.